# IMAP connection refused

Tags: debian, dovecot

I am running Postfix and Dovecot using IMAP and SSL using unix accounts. When running `openssl s_client -connect localhost:993` I get an error message `Connection Refused, Errno 111`.

Using telnet mail.example.com 25 and 587 return the correct responses.

I flushed iptables so it's empty with default ACCEPT. Any idea what to check?

**dovecot -n**

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap

service auth {
  unix_listener  /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  group = postfix
  mode = 0660
  user = postfix
  }
}

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}

ssl_cert = /path/to/cert
ssl_key = /path/to/cert
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Using Dovecot 2.x

Comment: Is anything actually listening on 993?

Comment: yes, dovecot is listening on 993

Comment: How sure are you of that? How have you checked this?

Comment: Yes, using netstat -tunlp | grep :993

Answer (score 1):

```
protocols = imap imaps
```

Source http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration

Comment: When I used imaps, dovecot told me this was no longer used and to use imap instead in the errors.

Comment: next time put in specifics, if you are using 2.x put 2.x
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Connection Refused generally means nothing is listening on the relevant IP:Port combination. Use netstat to confirm

```
netstat -tunlp | grep :993
```

take appropriate action depending on what you find.

Comment: Dovecot is not listening on 993. If I comment ssl = required, then dovecot listens on :143. Not sure what I'm missing to get it working with 993.

Comment: After commenting ssl = required in 10-ssl.conf it now listens on 993.

Comment: Ok, the issue was the SSL key file was in the wrong directory. Now I got 993 listening but I'm getting authentication errors when trying to login.